# Why is the word 'is' not considered a preposition?

Tags: grammar, verbs, prepositions

I am reading through the blue grammar book and the following is the definition of prepositions-

A preposition is a word or set of words that indicates location (in, near, beside, on top of) or some other relationship between a noun or pronoun and other parts of the sentence (about, after, besides, instead of, in accordance with). A preposition isn't a preposition unless it goes with a related noun or pronoun, called the object of the preposition.

If we consider the sentence- "he is honest", 'is' shows the relationship between 'he' and 'honest', it tells us he has the quality of honesty, I understand why it is considered a verb but do not understand how it is not a preposition as it satisfies the definition above?

Link for the relevant passage- https://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/probPrep.asp

Comment: I'll grant you that ***is*** is a very odd verb; perhaps the oddest in English and perhaps no longer a real verb. However, that's not the correct definition of a preposition. The source is simply wrong; find a better one. A preposition is a word that, when stuck before  a noun phrase, forms a larger phrase with that can modify many different things in a sentence. Never mind what it means. Grammar is not about meaning but form. Prepositions do not behave like verbs.

Comment: @JohnLawler could you please recommend a better textbook?

Comment: Possibly, depending on what you want it for. Certainly, without knowing your language background and needs, I can't.

Comment: @JohnLawler , I am a CS grad student and I am trying to read the textbooks in my field, I got a 109 on my TOEFL exam but I am afraid I do not know the rules of grammar, I can say what sounds right in most cases but I want to know the reasons why it is actually correct so I can understand what my text says at a deeper level, is there a book for my needs? for reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_of_English_as_a_Foreign_Language (TOEFL)

Comment: Look in a dictionary. *is* is a verb, it's a conjugation of *to be*.

Comment: If you're in CS and you either have or have access to native intuitions, you can probably benefit from McCawley's approach. He has a [syntax text](https://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/S/bo3613599.html) and a [semantics (logic) text](https://www.press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/E/bo3618384.html); I recommend both. They'll be in your university library.

Comment: Is your primary goal to understand how English grammar works? Or to understand your textbooks _'at a deeper level'_? I don't think that increasing your knowledge about grammar will have a significant influence on your comprehension of the texts you read (aside from the point that I don't really know what you mean by '_understand at a deeper level_).

Comment: The McCawley _Syntactic Phenomena_ text that John Lawler recommends is very good, but would be extremely challenging for anyone with no background in linguistics. A more accessible reference that I can recommend is _A Student's Introduction to English Grammar_ by the authors of the authoritative _The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language_.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> I'll grant you that ***is*** is a very odd verb; perhaps the oddest in English and perhaps no longer a real verb. However, that's not the correct definition of a preposition. The source is simply wrong; find a better one. A preposition is a word that, when stuck before  a noun phrase, forms a larger phrase with that can modify many different things in a sentence. Never mind what it means. Grammar is not about meaning but form. Prepositions do not behave like verbs.